# Getting CORS error *only* on server exception calling ASP.NET Core Web API from Angular 6

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have CORS in place and working. Meaning I get no CORS errors on GET or POST. My requests are all received on the server, and their responses are all received back on the client.

That is, UNLESS an exception occurs in the Web API. Then, instead of getting the exception detail, I get the CORS error. So the client cannot see the exception details.

> Failed to load
>   http://localhost:64630/api/sql/familiesCollection/create: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Here's the Configure method in my Startup class:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseCors(builder => builder
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod());

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

If the CORS request is accepted, and the CORS response is accepted back, why aren't the exception details in the event of an error also accepted back by the client?

Update... I implemented a more verbose version as per suggestion from Marcus; but to no avail. Still getting the very same CORS error in just the one case of attempting to return error data in a 500 response when an unhandled exception occurs in the Web API.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAllPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
    }));

    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<AppConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("AppConfig"));
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseCors("AllowAllPolicy");

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

And then, in my controller class:

```
[EnableCors("AllowAllPolicy")]
public class SqlApiController
{
    :
```

None of this is helping. CORS works until there's an exception in the Web API. Then, I get this, instead of exception info from the 500:

> Failed to load
>   http://localhost:64630/api/sql/familiesCollection/create: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Comment: Just curious, why is there a port different in both URL's?

Comment: Port 64630 is the Web API, being called from the client on port 4200. That's what makes it a CORS call. Problem is that I have CORS support working for all requests and responses. I only get the CORS error when there's an exception on the Web API side. Then, I expect to get the exception detail back on the client, not this CORS error.

Comment: How do the Web API throw the error/how is the error handled? Is there some global handler, e.g. filter?

Comment: That is by design. See here for more info: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2378

Comment: You need an explicit call to `app.UseExceptionHandler(...)`.  More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62437933/1370166).

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you don't have any specific limitations on your CORS config and you allow "All". In that case, this could help you.

I also see that you decorate your controller with the [EnableCors...] attribute, so on error it might be getting out of current controller and the error is handled "elsewhere", that is what might cause the the attribute to be out of scope...

I have used a simpler way, yet allows CORS and the errors are also "transported" to the client.

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Startup
    {

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

Then remove everything else that is related to CORS, this is enough for global enabled CORS and allows all origins (i.e. *).